# Shorten std::remove_const(decltype(something)) via "using" expression

Tags: c++, decltype

If I use C way, I can do following:

```
#define NOCONST(x) std::remove_const<decltype(x)>::type
const int a;
NOCONST(a) b;
```

If I use C++ way

```
template <typename T>
using noConst = std::remove_const<T>::type;
const int a;
noConst<decltype(a)> b;
```

Despite, that "using" is more correct, macro is shorter. Is there any way to further shorten "using" expression? without additional decltype in template parameter?

To clarify - I need use something like

```
noConst(a) b;
```

or

```
noConst<a> b;
```

without decltypes and other stuff in params. decltype shoulde be somehow moved to "using" expression, but I have no idea how or if is this possible overall.

Comment: May I ask why you have those restrictions?

Comment: @Jefery this exact case - for self-education

Comment: Is it for any `T` or just ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Especially in the form you are requiring. It may be possible to use type deduction in function contexts like this:

```
template<typename Type>
auto no_const(Type&&) { return typename std::decay<Type>::type(); }
```

but that would yield a syntax like this:

```
auto x = no_const(a);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f722911b33da73da)

**Diclamer**: the use of `std::decay` in the implementation may yield weird results with arrays and other "special" types; I haven't tested it; this is just a prototype.

I have to say that I highly discourage its use as it's really non-idiomatic C++. Just type those extra characters and use `decltype` in the object declaration.